# How to order the columns in my code with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Desired rendering On pc:
1 | 2

Desired rendering On mobile:
2
1

**How make that work with order classes?**

my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8"> 
         //1
         //order last on small screens
    </div>    
    <div class="col-lg-4"> 
         //2
         //order first on small screens
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Col-lg-8 will give col-8 class to screen sizes of large and above you need to use col-sm-8 to be able to use col-8 class on smaller screen sizes .

Comment: Will this _change the order_ the divs are displayed in? That's what OP is looking for.

Comment: It will change the display as col-sm-8 means give class of col-8 to all the screen sizes above small use bootstrap docs for more info